# Mysql выборка по числам через запятую

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим есть таблица новостей, в ней поле `category (varchar)`. Категорий может быть несколько, и это выглядит так:

```
id | category
1  | 1,2
```

То есть в данном случае первая новость идёт в двух категориях.

При выборке новости собственно нужно получить данные о категориях в которых она состоит.

Сразу в голову приходит стандартный вариант, делаем explode, затем выбираем данные по каждому числу (id категории).

Но возник вопрос, можно ли это всё сделать одним запросом, или как это сократить?

То есть что-то на подобии, `SELECT * FROM news JOIN categories ON news.category (цифры через запятую) IN categories.id`

Ну или если так не получится (что скорее всего вероятно) то можно ли получить данные категорий, напрямую передавая иды через запятую? То есть на подобии: `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id IN ACROSS COMA 1,4,9`

Comment: А с какой целью было придумано такое хранение? Чем не устроила классическая кросс-таблица?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov это движок сайта, не моя структура бд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
JOIN categories ON FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, news.category)
```

Comment: Спасибо, почти то. Но что делать если выборка данных категории происходит только у первой цифры в перечислении?

Comment: *выборка данных категории происходит только у первой цифры в перечислении?* Не верю. См. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b9baaNPu7YsJLRucyL3DEj/0

Comment: Да, вы правы. Забыл LIMIT убрать. Жаль лишь что в одну выборку нельзя поместить все названия категорий подходящих в перечислении, получаются дубляжи новостных записей.

Comment: *в одну выборку нельзя поместить все названия категорий подходящих в перечислении* Не понял фразы... может, просто нужны группировка по news.id и обёртывание categories.name в GROUP_CONCAT()?

Comment: Спасибо, вы гений.